# ¿Cómo se puede traducir "awesomeness"?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, sustantivos

En sentido positivo traduciría 'awesome' por *impresionante* (adjetivo). ¿Cómo seria la traducción de 'awesomeness'? Debería ser un nombre.

¿Podria ser ***impresionabilidad***?

Comment: No sé ¿Molonidad?

Comment: Pues al estilo Kung-Fu Panda (¿no habéis visto la película?): **¡Alucinancia!**

Comment: En México fue "asombrosidad" si mal no recuerdo, alucinancia también me cuadra :)

Comment: Pues asombrosidad puede cuadrar :)

Comment: `-bilidad` es `-ble` (posibilidad pasiva, es decir, capacidad o aptitud para recibir la acción del verbo [RAE]) + `-dad` (cualidad [RAE]); o sea, que tiene la cualidad de ser impresionable (ser impresionado). Impresionante es el que da, impresionable el que recibe.

Answer (score 7):

`Awesome` puede traducirse como "impresionante" o "asombroso", pero también como "genial" o "fantástico" (mira [esta entrada](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=awesome) de wordreference).

Si aceptamos que "genial" es una traducción válida para "awesome", `awesomeness` ([The quality of being awesome](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/awesomeness)) sería **"genialidad"**.

Otros sinónimos en ese sentido podrían ser **"grandiosidad"** (si aceptamos "grandioso" como posible traducción de "awesome").

Comment: Genialidad o grandiosidad no me cuadran con el sentido que le doy a 'awesomeness '. Creo que puede ser impresionante o asombroso sin ser genial o grande.

Comment: _Grandiosidad_ sí que está buena. Y por lo tanto también serviría _majestuosidad_.

Comment: **Grandiosa** respuesta. Aunque al OP no le cuadre para mi es la mejor y más "genérica" de las alternativas.

Comment: Asombroso, es lo que respondería yop. jeje

Answer (score 6):

Nada más empezar la película de *[Kung-Fu Panda](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0441773/)*, Po nos relata la historia de un maestro de las artes marciales, incluyendo la siguiente frase:

> He was so deadly, in fact, that his enemies would go blind from over-exposure to pure awesomeness!

Estoy seguro de que si en español hubiese una simple palabra para describir *awesomeness* la habrían usado, pero en vez de eso, la traducción dice:

> ¡Era tan letal que sus enemigos quedaban cegados por sobreexposición a su **"alucinancia"**!

Obviamente, en una traducción se ha de tener en cuenta el tiempo en el que se tarda en decir la frase para sincronizar el movimiento de los labios. Posiblemente haya una forma mejor de describirla en castellano, pero como neologismo me parece genial. A fin de cuentas:

> **[alucinante](http://dle.rae.es/?id=28eKbTs)**
>
> 1. adj. Que [alucina](http://dle.rae.es/?id=28fwlxV) [sorprende, asombra, deslumbra].

Y:

> **[-ncia](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QJb1Ewu)**
>
> 1. suf. Forma sustantivos femeninos abstractos, de significado muy variado, determinado por la base derivativa. Toma las formas **-ancia**, cuando la base derivativa termina en -ante, y **-encia**, cuando termina en -ente o -iente. *Extravagancia, importancia. Insistencia, dependencia.*

Por tanto, *alucinancia* sería un neologismo cuyo significado sería "la cualidad de ser alucinante". Y "alucinante" suele ser una traducción aceptada (aunque algo coloquial) para "awesome". Y de hecho en la película encaja muy bien y se entiende perfectamente lo que Po quiere expresar.

Esta palabra se ha hecho un pequeño hueco en la cultura popular. Si se busca en Google ahora mismo lo primero que sale es una referencia un espectáculo de un mago, cuyo nombre (el del espectáculo) es precisamente "Alucinancia". Si tratamos de eliminar de la búsqueda estas referencias, aún aparecen [alrededor de 37600 resultados](https://www.google.es/search?q=alucinancia%20-mago%20-jaque&oq=alucinancia%20-mago%20-jaque). Muchos, por supuesto, son referencias a la propia película de *Kung-Fu Panda*, pero el hecho de que la gente escriba usando o haciendo referencia a esta palabra, indica que ha calado, aunque sea mínimamente. A fin de cuentas, tampoco es una palabra que haga mucha falta usar en el habla cotidiana.

> There is no charge for awesomeness... or attractiveness.
>   *La alucinancia no tiene precio..., la atractividad tampoco.*

La RAE [me confirma por Twitter](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/912584848430288896) que, aunque la palabra *alucinancia* no tiene uso en español, sería el derivado que corresponde.

Comment: @walen por supuesto, yo creo que los traductores pensaron que ya que se habían inventado "alucinancia", otra palabra inventada como "atractividad" le sentaría bien al diálogo del personaje, para hacerlo así más desenfadado.

Comment: Alucinancia mola :)

Comment: [¿Mola?](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=PY47SMH|PY8VPJ5)

Answer (score 4):

Éste es un chilenismo:

> **[imponencia](http://dle.rae.es/?id=L5E6GAl)**
>
> **1**. f. *Chile, Col., R. Dom. y Ven.* Cualidad de imponente.

Por supuesto no es una gran respuesta porque según el DRAE solo lo usamos acá en Chile y en algunos países del Caribe. Se la escucharías decir a algún periodista deportivo y no mucho más que eso. Por ejemplo:

> Lo que más te sorprenderá de Santiago es la imponencia de la Cordillera de los Andes.
>
> ¡Con cuánta imponencia se ha presentado el equipo!

Deriva de

> **[imponente](http://dle.rae.es/?id=L5GTE1U)**
>
> **2**. adj. Formidable, que posee alguna cualidad extraordinaria.

Comment: Gracias, pero como dices, no me cuadra.

Answer (score 3):

Lo impresionante

Lo increíble

Lo ___________ (enorme, etc.)

> A: What did you like best about the Shostakovich?
>
> B: Oh, what can I say -- just the awesomeness of those big brass sounds filling the auditorium.
>
> A: ¿Qué fue lo que más te gustó de la sinfonía de Shostakovich?
>
> B: Ay, cómo explicártelo -- creo [que fue] lo impresionante de los metales, que llenaron el auditorio con su gran sonido.

Otro ejemplo:

> I love the awesomeness of the big Shostakovich brass sound.
>
> Me encanta lo enorme de los metales que es especial de Shostakovich.

*lo enorme* = "the enormousness"

Comment: La traducción en contexto me cuadra bastante. Gracias.